# how redisson serialize long

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I use redisson to store Long values:

```
        RSet<Long> set = client.getSet("myset");
        set.add(Long.valueOf(n));
```

But I get an unreadable value:

```
> SMEMBERS myset
1) "\t\x84\xe2\x02"
```

How can I retrieve this value without redisson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default codec for Redisson from version 3.13.0 is [MarshallingCodec](https://jbossmarshalling.jboss.org/) and before that it was [FSTCodec](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization). Both of these serialize to binary formats which are not human readable.

To serialize long and integer values Redisson offers LongCodec. The corresponding code will look like this:

```
RSet<Long> set = client.getSet("myset",LongCodec.INSTANCE);
set.add(Long.valueOf(n));
```